# Remove site from search engines for specific keyword

Tags: search-engines, google-search, yahoo, bing

I know normally people want the opposite but I would like to know if someone here knows how to remove a site from search results for a specific keyword.

Lately I'm getting a lot of visits from people who are actually looking for some other site. I know this because I did some research and it turns out the domain they're looking for is spelled slightly different.

Normally this wouldn't be a problem but in this case the people who are "accidentally" visiting my site are minors who are looking for some sort of game scam website. Most of them don't speak english and thus don't understand that my website is not the website they're looking for. Most of them are signing up 10 times in a row, trying to hack into my database and sending huge amounts of traffic using botnets.

All of this happens because my site ranks above the other site when they're searching for it. I don't want my site de-indexed from search engines, I just want to de-index it for that specific keyword.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: My initial reaction is that if your website can't handle traffic and hack attempts, it might be more worthwhile to make your website more robust, rather than trying to deter the demographic that is trying to hack it.

Comment: Thanks @MaximillianLaumeister. It's not that my website can't handle the traffic or hack attempts. It's more the annoyance of getting my email marked as spam because every time when someone signs up, a verification email is send. It's also cluttering up my database with fake email addresses. I already minimized a lot of the traffic by looking at several patterns like the search query in the referrer header, the immediate sign up when arriving on my site without looking at any content etc but this is far from ideal because it can be easily spoofed and might block out potential customers.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know any way to unrank a page for spesific keyword, the only think that would work is removing from your page (H1, Title, Descriptions, p) which are related to the keyword.

This is what [John Muller said](https://www.seroundtable.com/archives/019771.html) about the specific matter:

> If you rank for a phrase that you don't want to rank for, there's not
> much you can do other than make sure that your content does not
> include this phrase. Adjusting the description meta-tag and the title
> element to give more information about what you are really writing
> about can be helpful as well, although this may not affect your
> ranking for that phrase. Adding a "not" qualifier won't really help to
> change the ranking, but it might help users who are looking for
> something particular.
>
> One trick you could try is to replace individual letters with
> alternate glyphs that look very similar. For instance, you could
> replace a lower case "L" with the number "1" (or use cyrillic
> characters that look very similar, eg "e"/"е", "r"/"г", "i"/"і",
> etc.). While this would make it harder for us to understand your
> content (say if someone wanted to use Google Translate to read it in
> their own language), it would likely also prevent your content from
> ranking for those words.

Comment: There are no "i" in Russian language.  And "r" looking bad. L for 1 bad way too.

Comment: There are list of good, looking very similar: у cC еЕ хХ аА Рр оО0 (last is zero, looking not very similar) Copy and paste it.

Comment: Thanks @John. I don't think removing the h1 tags or title / description meta is a good idea. This will probably have a negative impact on search ranking in general.

Comment: @LeonidMew yeah you could be right i never tried to unrank something. user10198470 sorry i didnt clarify i meant remove the words on h1, title and desc related to the keyword term you want to unrank from.

Comment: @JohnCould that might work but in this case it's a little bit difficult because the keyword is also the name of the business.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to remove keyword from index, only whole page(s)
If you make image with text, that keyword, it will leave index. (but looks not perfect)
Next Im not sure following will work, but try to split keyword to few tags, like `<span>key</span><span>word</span>`.
And 3 way, replace chars in word with similar chars from other language, for example **кеу**w**о**rd - bold letters are Russian.
Combine above two methods, and Google will not find keyword. However Google search are good in finding typos and in accidental writing on wrong keyboard layout(that's not the same as I suggest in 3 way).

Comment: Thanks for the creative solution @LeonidMew. Unfortunately I can't split keywords because it's actually 1 keyword with 1 character difference. At the moment the problem isn't big enough to compromise the layout by replacing words with images or Russian letters.