# Google displaying business for search terms related to a totally different business

Tags: seo, google, search, local-seo, google-local-search

Google is displaying our business for searches related to a totally different business.

We display for the terms "next lincoln, next opening times" & emrsh says we get a lot of traffic from these searches & these term also show in google ym business insights.

These are searches related to a national clothing retailer which has 2 branches in our city.

Google my business support have told us that it's a good thing but we literally get people calling us asking about clothing when we are a printing business.

What can we do?

Comment: Is your business showing up in Google my business local search or SERP?

Comment: Both for normal search terms related to our business & also these unrelated terms.

Answer (score 1):

In this case i assume "lincoln" is included in your domain name and in meta data.

Since the word is mentioned in the domain is really hard to unrank from this query what you can do to probably drop some positions in to remove "lincoln" from the meta data, which i wont recommend.

I think this is a great opportunity to instead of walking away try to take advantage of this, is boosting your over all page rank anyway, you can probably convert some of those users, or simply let them boost your site.

To prevent people from communication the only thing that you can probably do is change the landing page and make sure the people can understand that is a printing business and not a clothing retailer.

Unranking for specific term is really tricky process check out this related post from another user: [Remove site from search engines for specific keyword](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118628/remove-site-from-search-engines-for-specific-keyword/)

Comment: "Next" is the first word of the domain name as it's the first word of the business name (ironically we switched away from an EMD due to offering more services in more areas) & lincoln is in the meta title & tag (as we're a service area business & this is the main search term) You'd think google would be more savvy nowadays & not be showing us for a totally unrelated business.

Comment: Google is one of the world smartest bots but it can still be considered a "dump" bot. We got to do the rest, in your case i think removing lincoln from the meta data wont necessarily unrank you completely from the term but it will definitely drop rankings on the mentioned search queries.

Comment: The issue is that would also drop all of our rankings for the main search term which we've always ranked #1 for in a time when we have fierce new competition so I can't do that. Just checked insights & it says 73% of the searches that find our business are branded....the problem is it's not our brand.

Comment: Then if unranking for this term is not an option try to take advantage of it. I will try to post some techniques to take advantage of un-related incoming traffic.